# c# drawing library calculate ranges and midpoints to draw and circle

Tags: c#, system.drawing

Basically i have a menu that user choose the shape wanted to be drawn, then the user click on two points, between those two points the chosen shape will be drawn.
I did the Square which is calculated this way

```
// calculate ranges and mid points
xDiff = oppPt.X - keyPt.X;
yDiff = oppPt.Y - keyPt.Y;
xMid = (oppPt.X + keyPt.X) / 2;
yMid = (oppPt.Y + keyPt.Y) / 2;

// draw square
g.DrawLine(blackPen, (int)keyPt.X, (int)keyPt.Y,
    (int)(xMid + yDiff / 2), (int)(yMid - xDiff / 2));
g.DrawLine(blackPen, (int)(xMid + yDiff / 2), (int)(yMid - xDiff / 2),
    (int)oppPt.X, (int)oppPt.Y);
g.DrawLine(blackPen, (int)oppPt.X, (int)oppPt.Y,
    (int)(xMid - yDiff / 2), (int)(yMid + xDiff / 2));
g.DrawLine(blackPen, (int)(xMid - yDiff / 2),
    (int)(yMid + xDiff / 2), (int)keyPt.X, (int)keyPt.Y);
```

but i can't figure out how to draw the circle and the triangle the same way

Please advise, thanks

Comment: To draw a circle you should use [DrawEllipse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads); to draw a triangle... well, how can you draw a traingle just by knowing two points?

Comment: @Marco i do know that but the question is how to calculate the size based on the user mouse click events on the windows form

Comment: On your square function you already have _oppPt_ and _keyPt_, aren't they user selected points?

Comment: they are and i managed to draw the square , i am trying to find the equation to use these selected points to draw a circle and triangle

Comment: Avoid multiple DrawLine commands for one DrawLines commead. And for a closed rectangle use DrawRectangle. For a Triangle use DrawPolygon !

Comment: each of them in it's own function, i am looking only here for the equation :)

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want it to do? How is it working now, do you have an image as an example? just draw it in paint and specify what two points you want to use to specify the shapes you want. What equation are you looking for? to draw a circle you can't really use lines, you have to use the `DrawEllipse` or `DrawArc` methods. Circles can be defined by their diameter, which you can get from two points, but then have to find the center,then the x and y position and the width and height to use `DrawEllipse`. What kind of triangle are you making with only two points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Same Way.

```
int left = 20, top = 20
int right = 100, bot = 100;

// triangle
g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, left, bot, right, bot);
g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, right, bot, left + (right-left) / 2 /* was miss calc */, top);
g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, left + (right - left) / 2, top, left, bot);  // better looks
//g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, left, bot, left + (right-left) / 2 /* was miss calc */, top);

// circle
int len = (right - left) / 2;
int centerX = left + (right - left) / 2, centerY = top + (bot - top) / 2;
for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
{
    int degrees = i;
    double radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

    int x = centerX + (int)(len * Math.Cos(radians));
    int y = centerY + (int)(len * Math.Sin(radians));
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x, y, 1, 1); // single pixel drawing
}
```

But Ellipse is more difficult

http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/computational-geometry/finding-angle-around-ellipse/

Upper link is help for Ellipse

Comment: only if he actually wants a rotated ellipse. Even then  it is recommended to rotate the graphics object instead..

Comment: @TaW If you said about GraphicsPath, I agree to your comment.
But he looks a newbie. So this way is more clearly.

Comment: @서강원 it's working but i don't the triangle only working on the top left side as the X and Y set in ur answer by 20 ,20

Comment: @user22387 I was miss calculating :D

Comment: i meant these two lines
int left = 20, top = 20
int right = 100, bot = 100;

Comment: @user22387 That is not problem on. Just set left and top to old point, And right and bot to next point

Comment: @user22387 I guess KetPt is previous selected point, and oppPt is next selected point on your code

Comment: Managed to draw first two lines but third one is a bit hard
 g.DrawLine(blackPen, (int)keyPt.X, (int)keyPt.Y, (int)(xMid + yDiff / 2), (int)(yMid - xDiff / 2));
            g.DrawLine(blackPen, (int)(xMid + yDiff / 2), (int)(yMid - xDiff / 2), (int)oppPt.X, (int)oppPt.Y);

Comment: @user22387 Oh, I started on (left, BOTTOM) and goto (right, BOTTOM) and goto top. Not started on (left, top). Bottom is oppPt.y on your code.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a circle, use `g.DrawEllipse`, here is a nice extension method for it:

```
public static void DrawCircle(Graphics g, Pen pen, float centerX, float centerY, float radius)
{
    g.DrawEllipse(pen, centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius + radius, radius + radius);
}
```

To draw filled, simply change `DrawEllipse` to `FillElipse` and `Pen` to `Brush`:

```
public static void DrawCircleFilled(Graphics g,  Brush brush, float centerX, float centerY, float radius)
{
    g.FillEllipse(brush, centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius + radius, radius + radius);
}
```

If you insist on drawing shapes only with lines, then fear not. A trinagle is simply drawn with three lines, that's fairly easy so I won't write that here. As for a circle:

Circle is made out of a several segments, the more segments, the better the quality of a circle. You can start with a simple triangle, then add one more line and you have a square, then pentagon, hexagon and so one. With each line the shapes resembles more of a circle optically.

[image]

As you can see, each line covers (360 / N) of the total angle. So you can use a for cycle to draw all segments (lines).

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am a beginner still and it was a bit confusing for me

Comment: No it didn't help

Comment: @LarsTech from OP's first comment I thought he/she has resolved the issue, describing it as "it was a bit confusing [problem] for me [but I've solved it now]"

Answer (score 0):

If you specify with two points((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) the diameter of the circle,
then use `DrawEllipse` with x,y,w,h

x = cx-r

y = cy-r

d = w = h = sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)

where

cx = |x2-x1|/2

cy = |y2-y1|/2

r = d/2

For triangle you really need three points though. You could restrict it to two points as in specifying the hypotenuse of a right triangle. That still isn't enough information though because there are two right triangles that could have that hypotenuse, the upper and lower side. What kind of triangle do you want? right, iso, acute, equilateral, obtuse?